# The argument passed when initializing an observable array must be an array, or null, or undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I am very new to knockoutjs I got the error "The argument passed when initializing an observable array must be an array,or null,or undefined.I don't have an idea how to solve it.Can any one help me please.

```
 viewModel = function ()
 {
    var self = this;
    self.rows = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.items = ko.observableArray(childData.items);
    self.otherCharges = ko.observableArray(childData.otherCharges);
    self.add = function (type) {

        var entry = new Entry({});
         entry.SNo(VMRows().length);
        entry.Type(type);
        self.rows.push(entry);

    };

    self.remove = function (entry) {
        self.rows.remove(entry);
        i = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(VMRows, function (e) {
            e.SNo(i++);
        });
    };

};
VM[container] = new viewModel();

var VMRows = VM[container].rows;
```

Comment: Beware that your code, as quoted, is falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. Declare your variables (such as `viewModel`).

Answer (score 3):

The message is very clear: You're passing a value into `ko.observableArray` that isn't an array, `null`, or `undefined`. So that tells us that either `childData.items` or `childData.otherCharges` is not an array, not `null`, and not `undefined`. At least one of them is some *other* value. (Obviously I can't tell you which; you haven't show us what `childData` is.)

Comment: Hi,T.J.Crowder   <script>
    var childData={items:@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.xShiftA)),
        otherCharges:@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.xShiftB)),
        rows:@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.xDetails))};
</script>    is my script and in my project I have to you two knockoutjs lists for shiftA&B but no items were displayed when I click Edit

Comment: @Sowjanya: Quoting server-side templating code in a comment is not useful. Show what the browser sees, not the server code, using the "edit" link on the question. Now I can' thelp because I don't know what `Model.xShiftA` and `Model.xShiftB` are. (And I don't need to know. I just need to know what the *browser* sees.)

Comment: Hi,T.J.Crowder,thank you for your valuable answer.As u did I have declared some of the elements of child data as ko.observableArray which are not array elements.How I removed Array from ko.observableArray so my screen is working